# how to use train_image_classifier.py train both gender and age

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I was working on a face recognition project,I use train_image_classifier.py to classify age and gender,but this py is only train for one feature,how to train for much features

Comment: you need to show us your train_image_classifier.py. you can modify it to train multiple features on the file it self

Comment: this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py

Answer (score 0):

You should know that this is a multitask classification problem, the features are the images of faces (since this is a face recognition project) and the scopes will be the age and the gender.

For multitask classification, there will be 2 trainings running in parallel for each task (gender classification and age classification).

Basically you have to define 2 classifiers at the output of your CNN feature extractor.

I suggest you to read this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-an-age-and-gender-multi-task-predictor-with-deep-learning-in-tensorflow-20c28a1bd447). This is what you are looking for.

Hope it helps!